# SQLite3 with multiple WHERE

Tags: database, ios4, sqlite, char

I'm new to SQLite3 with iOS

I'm trying to create an SQL Query that will execute the following statement

```
SELECT student_name 
FROM class_roster 
WHERE 
  student_id='1' 
  AND student_first_name='Jon' 
ORDER BY student_first_name;
```

In my iOS code, i'm getting the data from textfields.

Any help would be appreciated. (I just need to know how to create the `string` or `char*`)

I saw this in a book but not sure how to use it

```
char *cQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT country 
  FROM countryTable 
  WHERE nationName LIKE ? 
  ORDER BY nationName";
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,cQuery, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) { 
  NSLog(@"query error: %s", statement); 
}
```

How do I put more than 1 value? How does the application know what the `?` does?

Thanks

Comment: Your sample query seems a bit odd; ordering by a field when you're doing an equality constraint on the field? That's just having the rows in random order, you know…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code prepares a statement. You have a bit of extra work e.g. by binding values to the wilcards "?". This is documented here: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html

```
if (sqlite3_bind_double( 
      statement,
      1,  // Index of wildcard
      4.2 // Value
      ) != SQLITE_OK) {
  // Error handling...
}
```

Execute the statement and do sth. with the result.
http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html